# Is there a mitzvah of bedikat chametz in cars

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, orach-chaim, bedikas-chametz

According to Halacha are Jews obligated to do bedikat chametz before Passover in cars? Or no, is there not an active obligation to search for chametz before Pesach in cars?

Comment: לחפש אחר החמץ במחבואות ובחורים ולבדק ולהוציאו מכל גבולו

Answer (score 9, accepted):

R’ Benzion Abba Shaul in [Ohr Ltziyon 3:7;9](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19980&st=&pgnum=69) says that you need to check a car and that if that’s the only thing you have, you’d have to make a bracha as well.

R’ Shlomo Zalman Halicos Shlomo Nissan page 111 says that although one must check a car, a bracha should not be made as the takana was to only make a bracha when checking a home.

Comment: Its important to note that you should check your car while under the same Bracha you made on your house. first say the bracha, check your house, then move on to the car.